code compiles on other compilers, but returns an error when used in visual studio
This code in C works properly when I use code::blocks or any online compilers, however if I try to use this in VSCODE it returns
"expected type-specifier before ';' token on LN 5, Col 18"
"expected type-specifier before ')' token on LN 13, Col 26"
"expected type-specifier before ')' token on LN 20, COL 21"
this is the code that i was referring to
+
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char operator;
    double num1;
    double num2;
    double result;
    char choice;

    do {
    printf("Enter the operator you want to use: ");
    scanf("%c", &operator);

    printf("Number 1: ");
    scanf("%lf", &num1);
    printf("Number 2: ");
    scanf("%lf", &num2);

    switch (operator)
    {
    case '+':
        result = num1 + num2;
        printf("The Sum is: %.1lf\n", result);
        break;
    case '-':
        result = num1 - num2;
        printf("The Difference is: %.1lf\n", result);
        break;
    case '/':
        result = num1 / num2;
        printf("The Quotient is: %.3lf\n", result);
        break;
    case '*':
        result = num1 * num2;
        printf("The Product is: %.1lf\n", result);
        break;

    default:
    printf("That is not a valid operator! \n");
        break;
    }

    printf("Do you want to compute again?: Y/N ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    choice = toupper(choice);
    while ((getchar()) != '\n');

    }while (choice == 'Y');

    return 0;
}


I tried changing the char operators; but to no avail. this problem shows up on VSC only

I'm only guessing here, since you don't give us details about how you build the program (or the name of the source file).... You build the program as a C++ program, which means operator is a keyword that you can't use for variable names.

And not a problem yet, but you need to check the return value from scanf() to make sure it actually read data.  If the user types QWERTY, scanf("%lf", &num2); won't read any data and will leave that string in the input buffer.

That is the exact error you get when compiling your code as a C++ program.
It's not a valid C++ program since operator (as in char operator;) is a keyword in C++ and you can't declare variable named operator in C++. You need to save your program as a C program and compile it as such.
